# Can CURLOPT_COOKIELIST be set on a different curl easy handle?

Tags: c++, http, cookies, libcurl

I'm trying to perform a file upload operation(which is done using multiple HTTP POST requests).  Hence I need to save the cookies from the response of first HTTP POST and set those cookies in the request of the second HTTP POST. I save cookies using CURLINFO_COOKIELIST and set them manually using CURLOPT_COOKIELIST.

CURLcode result = curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_COOKIELIST, my_cookies)
This works only if I set the cookies on the same curlHandle. If I close the handles and create new ones after each request, it fails.

Is it not possible to use CURLOPT_COOKIELIST option on different curl handles to execute multiple HTTP requests in the same session ?
Any help is much appreciated.

Update: 
I'm trying to save and set the cookies like this. Is there anything wrong I might be doing ?

```
std::string my_cookies;
// Setting other options using curl_easy_setopt

// To start the cookie engine              
curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,"");
if (!my_cookies.empty())
{
 curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_COOKIELIST, my_cookies);
}
curl_easy_perform(curlHandle);

// Save cookies from response of first HTTP POST
struct curl_slist* cookies;
curl_easy_getinfo(curlHandle,CURLINFO_COOKIELIST,&cookies);
// Code to copy cookies to my_cookies.
```

Comment: I don't see any way that the cookie list is tied to a specific handle.

Comment: Post your code so we can see what you're doing wrong. If you're using multiple threads, maybe the problem is that you don't have a mutex around uses of `my_cookies`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in an extracted cookie list that binds it to that particular easy handle so yes, it can be moved over and inserted into another handle.